# How to get and modify the Date value

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I'm working on a Reactjs project and I have to set up a warranty date.
This warranty date is the Installation date + 1 year.

In my code when I create a Client I can put an Installation Date. This date is entered by a Date Picker [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker).

**Here is my code, the solution :**

```
class CreateClient extends React.Component {
  state = {
    installDate: null,
    warrantyDate: null
  };

  handleChange = date => {
    const warrantyDate = new Date(new Date(date).getTime() + 86400000 * 365);
    this.setState({
      installDate: date,
      warrantyDate
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, translate, ...props } = this.props;
    return (
      <Create {...props} title={<ClientCreateTitle />}>
        <TabbedForm>
          <FormTab label="resources.client.tabs.identity">
            <TextInput autoFocus source="name" required />
            <TextInput
              type="email"
              source="email"
              validation={{ email: true }}
              formClassName={classes.email}
              validate={[required(), email()]}
            />
            <TextInput
              type="phone"
              source="phone"
              validation={{ phone: true }}
              formClassName={classes.phone}
            />
          </FormTab>
          <FormTab label="resources.client.tabs.address" path="address">
            <LongTextInput
              source="address"
              formClassName={classes.address}
              label="resources.client.localisation.address"
              required
            />
            <TextInput
              source="zipcode"
              formClassName={classes.zipcode}
              label="resources.client.localisation.zipcode"
              required
            />
            <TextInput
              source="city"
              formClassName={classes.city}
              label="resources.client.localisation.city"
              required
            />
            <TextInput
              source="country"
              formClassName={classes.country}
              label="resources.client.localisation.country"
              required
            />
          </FormTab>
          <FormTab label="resources.client.tabs.equipment" path="equipment">
            {/* <DateInput
          source="installAt"
          label="resources.client.info.installationDate"
        /> */}
            <DatePicker
              selected={this.state.installDate}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <DisabledInput
              source="warrantyDate"
              label="Date de garantie (Automatique)"
              defaultValue={this.state.warrantyDate}
            />
          </FormTab>
        </TabbedForm>
      </Create>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(CreateClient);
```

I don't know how to set up my warranty date.

#### Edit for Dupocas

I got 2 errors with this method :

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` supplied to `TextField`.
```

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` supplied to `Input`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the following date

```
const date = new Date('2019-10-01')
```

One of many ways of incrementing a date is to use `getTime()` and add the correspondent `ms` before converting it back to a legible `date`

```js
   const date = new Date('2019-10-01')
   const oneYearFromNowInMs = date.getTime() + (86400000 * 365) //ms in a day times 365
   const newDate = new Date(oneYearFromNowInMs)
   console.log(newDate)
```

Now assume this `Component`

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    state = {
        startDate : null,
        warrantyDate : null
    }

    handleChange = date => {
        const warrantyDate = new Date(new Date(date).getTime() + (86400000*365))
        this.setState({
            startDate: date,
            warrantyDate
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <DatePicker
                selected={this.state.startDate}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
             />
        )
    }
}
```

If you need to perform many operations involving dates you should definitely take a look [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)

Comment: Ok I understand. I write this `const warrantyDate = installDate.getTime() + (86400000 * 365)` but can I write a const inside a class ? I don't know the syntax

Comment: I'm updating my answer to include a react's use case

Comment: Now looks better

Comment: `defaultValue={this.state.warrantyDate}` Warranty date is part of state now

Comment: I got 2 errors with this method, please check the edited post.

Comment: Could you please update you code as well? I can't see the `value` prop in your current code

Comment: My code is already updated, the error is about the defaultValue prop I think. Because if I comment it the error disapears.